# Lithium thionyl chloride for GSM application

Tags: batteries, low-power, msp430, gsm

I'm trying o use a LiSoCl2 battery in a low power GSM application. When the system is in standby only the microcontroller(MSP430) is powered(3.3v) and the GSM(5v) and sensor(5v) is turned off. The whole system consumes 50uA. The burst current when sending data over GSM is up to 2A, but my battery provides a maximum 400mA of discharge current. Some applications use auxiliary capacitor, but most capacitors have high leakage current.
The converter used for provide 5v is LMR61428, when the system is in standby mode it is turned off.

What is the best way to avoid leakage current of an auxiliary capacitor?
Is there a way to enable the capacitor only moments before using GSM to prevent leakage current?

Comment: Are you equating high ESR with high leakage? And what does "high" mean in your case?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected the question. I want to prevent capacitor leakage.

Comment: How much leakage are you expecting from your capacitor?

Comment: If you know in advance when you (likely) need it you could start charging the capacitor then.  But depending on network behavior it might take more energy than expected to get your message out. This will be a very challenging project to get right.

Comment: How much capacitance do you need?

Comment: The way I have dealt with this in the past is to charge up a capacitor immediately prior to the transmit cycle. There are low leakage devices around. What is the effective duty cycle? 10 seconds every hour? every day? Details matter for this.

Comment: Have you considered putting two LiSoCl2 cells in series, and using a buck converter instead? You may use only one of the cells during the sleep cycle, or a very efficient micropower buck converter for the 3.3V rail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Manufacturers of lithium thionyl chloride battery packs use hybrid layer capacitors (HLCs) for this exact purpose. For example see [Tadiran](https://tadiranbatteries.de/eng/products/pulses-plus-batteries/hybrid-layer-capacitors-hlc.asp).